# Bootstrap Buttons Won't Display Properly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

### My Problem

I am trying to add 3 big buttons ( Summary, Builder, History ) in the middle of my nav bar. Below is pictured my ideal results. I would like an active one to have no bottom border.

[image: Desired Results]

I have tried everything I can think of to get this to work. When I add a button in the spot you would think it should go, here is what I get:

[image: Attempt]

Notice the yellow oval, that is where my button is ending up!! I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

Here is a link to the page, as to post the code here would be too long:

http://johntesting.azurewebsites.net/workflow-blue/blank-backup.html

Can anyone help me out with these buttons? I have been going crazy trying to figure this out.

Thanks for looking.

John

Comment: have you tired z-index?

Comment: There is no HTML code here and even on the page that you included there are no buttons

Comment: I apologize, there was a problem FTP. I am re-uploading the project now. Must have had a hiccup during upload.

Comment: OK the link is updated. Again, my apologies.   http://johntesting.azurewebsites.net/workflow-blue/blank-backup.html

Answer (score 0):

Set `display:flex;` on your '.page_title' div to immediately see the button much closer to where you expect it. The first child element of that div is an h3 which is a block element that fills the entire div, leaving no room for your buttons, resulting in them being pushed to the next line.

Another approach is to set the display property of that h3 to inline-block.

Comment: Thanks JasonB, I am trying out this suggestion now.